# How display id of most recent modified post in wordpress?

Tags: theme-development

Hi somebody please help me.
I need display id of last modified post in my wordpress template.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the request by adding the orderby parameter: `modified`

```php
$args = [
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
];
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

[WP_query Order & Orderby Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters)

Comment: You can limit it to just a single post with `'posts_per_page` => 1` as well

Comment: Hey Thanks. but how echo that?